# How to get minimum value by week using Pandas and Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that looks like this that I get from an API (of course in JSON form):

```
0,1500843600,8872
1,1500807600,18890
2,1500811200,2902
.
.
.
```

where the second column is the date/time in ticks, and the third column is some value. I basically have the data for every hour of the day, for every day for a couple of months. Now, what I want to achieve is that I want to get the minimum value for the third column for every week. I have a code segment that looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import json
import pandas

# Partially removed for brevity.
# dic holds now the data that I get from the API.
dic = json.loads(soup.prettify())

df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp', 'Value'])

for i in range(len(dic)):
    df.loc[i] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(dic[i][1])).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), dic[i][2]]

df.sort_values(by=['Timestamp'])
df['Timestamp'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df.set_index(df['Timestamp'], inplace=True)

print(df['Value'].resample('W').min())
```

Though, this does not quite give me correct results, also some of the results are `NaN`. Additionally, I also want to get the timestamp along with the minimum value, so I know at which date/time during the week the minimum occurred. Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pandas [grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) functions

```
>>> data = [[0,1500843600,8872],[1,1500807600,18890],[2,1500811200,2902]]
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'Timestamp', 'Value'])
   id   Timestamp  Value
0   0  1500843600   8872
1   1  1500807600  18890
2   2  1500811200   2902
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'Timestamp', 'Value'])
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
0   1970-01-01 00:00:01.500843600
1   1970-01-01 00:00:01.500807600
2   1970-01-01 00:00:01.500811200
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
>>> df
   id                     Timestamp  Value
0   0 1970-01-01 00:00:01.500843600   8872
1   1 1970-01-01 00:00:01.500807600  18890
2   2 1970-01-01 00:00:01.500811200   2902
>>> df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='W-MON')])['Value'].min()
Timestamp
1970-01-05    2902
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

You might also want to take a look at the [Anchored offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) because you can pick W frequencies starting on different days

-- Edit --
As MaxU suggested below if you want to keep the timestamp in seconds then use `df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, unit='s')`

Comment: try to use `df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, unit='s')`